# Elementor pro horizontal scrolling not working on mobile view

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, elementor, horizontal-scrolling

Good day to anyone who is reading this.
**THE PROBLEM**
So basically I am using elemntor pro to create a horizontal scrolling website and I have successfully achieved that with a bit of code but just have one issue so the website scrolls horizontally on all screen dimensions just that on mobile portrait it scrolls vertically so basically I want the website to scroll horizontally across all screen dimensions. Below I have also mentioned and written down the code that I am using.

**THE CODE**
On elementor page settings I am using this code:

```
scroll-behavior: {auto;
}
    main {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      display: flex;
    }
     @media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    main {
      display: flex;
      overflow-x:auto;
      overflow-y:hidden;
    }
}
 

    section {
      min-width: 100vw!important;
      min-height: 100vh!important;
    }
```

and on the page itself I have dropped a HTML widget where I am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.innerWidth > 1025) {
       const scrollContainer = document.querySelector("main");

        scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
            evt.preventDefault();
            scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;
        });
    } else {

}
</script>
```

Link to the page I am talking about is:
https://staging.austingualazzi.com/home-page/